# Parsing string on multiple parts without separator

Tags: shell-script, string

```
115:wc -l:find . -iname "*test*":find /tmp/ -iname "*test*"
```

I would like to parse the string above.

In my case, a string consists of 4 columns (every command has `:` separator) but it can be much longer. 
I want to "pull out" all the commands including initial number, starting with `115` and continuing with `wc -l, -iname "*test*"`, `find /tmp/ -iname "*test*"` ... always without `:` separator.

My variable `$var` should get those values:

```
var= 115 , var= wc-l , var= find . -iname "*test*" , var= find /tmp/ -iname "*test*"
```

My code:

```
while read line;
 do
 while [[ $var -ne '0' ]];
   do
    var=$( echo $line | cut -d ':' -f$i )
    i=$( expr $i + 1 )
    echo $var
   done
done <$1
```

I read lines from file and with second while I cut columns until empty one. 
Obviously, there is something wrong because echo do not print anything.

Comment: Sounds a bit like you want us to do your homework. Can you elaborate on what you tried already?

Comment: Pardon me!
I tried to cut column by column but result is just not satisfying. 
var=$( echo $line | cut -d ':' -f1-4 | tr ':'  '\n' )

Comment: please elaborate on how your result was not satisfying and use the edit functionality to add it to the question. It will be easier to help you that way :)

Comment: I added some code :). Hope now is better to understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your script fixed to work the way I think you meant it to work:

```sh
i=1     
while read line;                        
  do     
  while :; do 
    var=$( echo $line | cut -d ':' -f$i )                                   
    i=$( expr $i + 1 ) 
    [[ "$var" != "" ]] || break
    echo $var
  done     
done <$1
```

A couple of remarks:

- `i` was not initialized
- `var` was not initialized either, so the inner loop would not execute even once
- I'm not sure what `[[ $var -ne '0' ]]` tests, but I think comparing `$var` to an empty string is better.
- As a consequence, if there is an enpty field (i.e. two consecutive colons), this script will terminate there

A more robust way of doing the same thing is:

```
while read line; do
  num_fields=$(echo $line|awk -F':' '{print NF}')
  for (( i=1; i <= num_fields; i++ )); do
    var=$( echo $line | cut -d ':' -f$i )
    echo $var
  done
done <$1
```